# Create simple Junit @rule

Tags: junit

I've just discovered JUnit Rules.

I have a Groovy unit test case as follows...

```
class CheckRegistrationValidatorTest {

    @Test
    void 'input validation'() { 
        def checkRegistrationValidator = 
               new CheckRegistrationValidator(regexCarTruckRegNo:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$/, regexMotorcycleRegNo:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,5}$/, regexTrailorRegNo:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$/, regexBoatRegNo:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$/, regexVin:/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})$/, regexChassis:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$/)
        def input = [
                vehicleClassCode: '0',
                vehicleIdentificationType: 'registrationNumber',
                vehicleRegistrationNumber: 'WEB001'
            ]   
        checkRegistrationValidator.validate input
    }

}
```

I want to replace the checkRegistrationValidator instantiation with an @ClassRule. I've attempted to read up on them but I'm just not getting it.

Can someone help me with how to create a @ClassRule just to do that line of code.

thanks

Comment: Why do you need a rule?  You can just declare it as a class member variable.

Comment: I agree! I'm just trying to go with the flow. I thought these class member variables were meant to be changed into @Rules? Perhaps the use case does not suit?

Comment: Rules are intended to encapsulate some **behaviour** that happens before/after a test-case/class (good example being `TemporaryFolder` which creates/deletes a folder).  Given that you can do variable initialisation natively in Java, there's really no need for a rule (as far as I can se).